# Check if JSON fits the needed class using GSON

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson

I have a class like

```
data class Data(
    val field1: Int = 123
    val field2: String = "Foo"
)
```

I have JSON like

```
{"field1": 123, "field2": "Foo"}
```

How can I check if my JSON really represents the structure of the class using Google GSON?

Comment: I don't think I have completely understood the question. if you use GSON to convert the json to object and check the values in it should do. 
*var gson = Gson()

var data: Data = gson.fromJson(*your_json*, Data.class)*

Comment: You can write a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) for your data. You'll have to think about what you consider valid or invalid. Since you have provided default values for your fields, I assume that it's ok if one or both of the properties are missing from your json input? How about extra properties that you haven't defined in your class, are you okay with receiving additional properties? That makes it easier to rollout new versions of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi bro there are several Ways first by using code

```
    import org.json.*;

public boolean isValidJSONTest(String yourjsonString) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(yourjsonString);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {

        try {
            new JSONArray(yourjsonString);
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**For Gson code is like**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    Object o = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
    System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(o));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("invalid json format");
}
```

second you can use browser console and paste your string in console and enter
[image]

**third they are several website that can validate json format or view etc
https://jsonlint.com/**